# Problem with obtaining title of a tooltip in selenium webdriver

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to find a way to obtain a title of a tooltip displayed on mouse over event
on a page:
https://demo.nopcommerce.com/nike-floral-roshe-customized-running-shoes

This tooltip appears when mouse is over 2 of "Print" items.
It is about header of this tooltip:

```
//*[@id="image-squares-8"]/li[1]/div/div[1]

//*[@id="image-squares-8"]/li[2]/div/div[1]
```

Natural

Fresh

How to get it programmaticaly in selenium webdriver?

I have such code:

```
        mainPage = mainPage.moveToApparel()
                .select()
                .selectNthProductOnPage(1) -- moves to above page
                .selectSize(8)  -- select size of shoes
                .selectColor("White/Black") -- select color on this page
                .moveToStyle(1); -- action.moveToElement(element);

        String text = mainPage.getStyleTooltip();  -- returns empty string!?
```

```
    public String getStyleTooltip() {
        // tooltip-header
        return tooltipHeader.getText();
    }
```

```
    @FindBy(css = "div[class='tooltip-header']")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement tooltipHeader;
```

in this code

```
mainPage.getStyleTooltip();
```

returns empty string, not current tooltip text.
How to obtain current tooltip text in this case?

BR,

fotrenc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tooltip is hidden when you are getting it's text.

`getText()` function returns text only for elements that are visible.

To get text from invisible element you can get element `innerHTML` attribute.

```java
public String getStyleTooltip() {
     return tooltipHeader.getAttribute("innerHTML");
 }
```

if you need to get current visible tooltip, you should hover it first and then filter elements from list and get first visible, smth like

```java
@FindBy(css = "div[class='tooltip-header']")
@CacheLookup
List<WebElement> tooltipHeaders;

public String getStyleTooltip() {
     return Stream.of(tooltipHeaders)
                .filter(el -> ((WebElement) el).isDisplayed())
                .findFirst().map(el -> ((WebElement) el).getAttribute("innerHTML")).orElse("");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Yaroslavm for an answer.
It works but it returns incorrect value - other than displayed title in tooltip. Probably I have a problem with css selector :/

Comment: What value? For me it returns Natural and Fresh for 1st and second element

Comment: My goal is to obtain correct value from tooltip header when tooltip is displayed. 
So after executing actions:


```.moveToStyle(1); -- action.moveToElement(element);```

at this moment tooltip should appear

```String text = mainPage.getStyleTooltip();  -- returns empty string!?```


variable 'text' should have correct value of tooltip header from displayed at this moment tooltip.
Maybe I incorrectly emphasized what I want to achieve.

Comment: @fotrenc if you need to get currently visible element, you should get list of elements and filter them by visibility, get first one and get it's attribute `innerHTML`. Or even `getText()` can work in this case. 

Try second snippet. I can't test by myself your resource because of Cloudflare.